# Email option embeded in Submit button Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this Submit button and I want to send an email notification to a person regarding on the status of the Quality checking. I want to happen is if the Quality Checker ticked a Checkbox the Caption for all selected checkbox will be included in. Body of EMail but I cant figure it out on how to code. here is my Submit button code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
If VERIFY_ENTRY = False Then Exit Sub
Dim RowCounter  As Long
Dim rowCount    As Long
Dim ctrl        As Control
Dim Score       As Double
Dim num As String

Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody1 As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim strbody As String
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

RowCounter = 0
Score = 1

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
    Case Is = "CheckBox"
        If Me.Controls(ctrl.Name).Value = True Then Score = Score - GETSCORE(Me.Controls(ctrl.Name).Name)
    End Select
Next ctrl
Me.TextBox6.Value = Format(Score, "Percent")

If MsgBox("Submit RFP results?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "") = vbNo Then GoTo endmacro

'Data Sheet Transfer
rowCount = Worksheets("Quality Database").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Quality Database").Range("A" & rowCount + 1)

    .Offset(RowCounter, 0).Value = Now()
    .Offset(RowCounter, 1).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    .Offset(RowCounter, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    .Offset(RowCounter, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    .Offset(RowCounter, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
    .Offset(RowCounter, 6).Value = "Initial prep/load"

    .Offset(RowCounter, 9).Value = Me.ComboBox4.Value

    .Offset(RowCounter, 10).Value = Round(Score * 100, 2)
    .Offset(RowCounter, 11).Value = Format(Me.TextBox3.Value, "hh:mm:ss")    'Start Time
    .Offset(RowCounter, 12).Value = Format(Me.TextBox4.Value, "hh:mm:ss")   'End Time
    .Offset(RowCounter, 13).Value = Format(Me.TextBox5.Value, "hh:mm:ss")   'Time Spent
    .Offset(RowCounter, 13).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

    ' Attributes Target
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case Is = "CheckBox"
            If Me.Controls(ctrl.Name).Value = True Then
            'if not other checkbox
            If Me.Controls(ctrl.Name).Caption <> "Other" Then
             .Offset(RowCounter, 7).Value = vbCrLf & Me.Controls(ctrl.Name).Caption
                RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                Else
                'get number from checkbox name
                num = Mid(ctrl.Name, 9)
                .Offset(RowCounter, 7).Value = vbCrLf & Me.Controls(ctrl.Name).Caption
                .Offset(RowCounter, 8).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & num).Value
                RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                End If
            End If
        End Select
    Next ctrl
    If RowCounter = 0 Then .Offset(RowCounter, 7).Value = "Everything was Completed Satisfactory!"

    If Me.ComboBox4.Value = "Pending - Team Meeting" Then
   .Offset(RowCounter, 7).Value = ""
   .Offset(RowCounter, 10).Value = ""
   End If
   If Me.ComboBox4.Value = "Pending - 1st Break" Then
   .Offset(RowCounter, 7).Value = ""
   .Offset(RowCounter, 10).Value = ""
   End If
   If Me.ComboBox4.Value = "Pending - Lunch Break" Then
   .Offset(RowCounter, 7).Value = ""
   .Offset(RowCounter, 10).Value = ""
   End If
   If Me.ComboBox4.Value = "Pending - 2nd Break" Then
   .Offset(RowCounter, 7).Value = ""
   .Offset(RowCounter, 10).Value = ""
   End If
   If Me.ComboBox4.Value = "Pending - Coaching" Then
   .Offset(RowCounter, 7).Value = ""
   .Offset(RowCounter, 10).Value = ""
   End If

End With

'MessageBox
 MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, ""
endmacro:
'Clear Data

If Me.ComboBox4.Value = "Completed" Then ' Enable Email Notification

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

       With OutMail
        .Display
        If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Name1" Then
        .To = "name@email`enter code here`.com"
        End If
        If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Name2" Then
        .To = "name@email.com"
        End If
        If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Name3 " Then
        .To = "name@email.com"
        End If
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = TextBox2.Value & " - Review Completed & " & Now()
        .Body = "Hi," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please see comment below"
        .Display 'change to .send if you want the email sent automatically

     End With
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
   End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

INIT_FORM
Me.TextBox2.SetFocus

'Save worksheet
 ThisWorkbook.Save



End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's clear to me where you are stuck.  Can you include the output you are currently getting Vs the output you want?

Comment: Actually the only result I'm getting is the template message for the .Body Section where is Hi, Please see comment below. And the additional message in the body should be the All the Caption ticked on all Checkbox. Thank you,

Comment: Of course, I meant to say; it's **not** clear to me where you are stuck.  My message about things being unclear was unclear.  Oh the shame.  It looks like you've created a couple of variables to build the body (`strbody`, `strbody1`) but you don't use these anywhere.  Is that because you are not sure how?  Or are you asking how to access the caption of a checkbox?

Comment: Yes on how to include the Caption of a checkbox in Body of Email and Sorry I forgot to remove those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/function-statement) will extract the caption from every selected checkbox on your form.

The function uses a [For Each...Next loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/for-eachnext-statement) to check each control.  I've used [vbCrLf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/miscellaneous-constants) to delimit the checkboxes with new lines, which should make the final text easier to read.

```
' Builds and returns the email body.
Private Function GetMailBody() As String
    Dim i As Integer            ' Counts number of selected checkboxes.
    Dim mailBody As String      ' Build the email message body here.
    Dim cntl As Control         ' Used to loop over controls, looking for checkboxes.

    ' Add body.
    For Each cntl In Me.Controls

        ' We only want checkboxes.
        If TypeName(cntl) = "CheckBox" Then

            ' Append selected boxes caption to mailBody.
            If cntl.Value = True Then 
                i = i + 1
                mailBody = mailBody & vbCrLf & cntl.Caption
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Update body, based on count of selected items.
    If i > 1 Then

        mailBody = "Opening text" & vbCrLf & mailBody & vbCrLf & "Closing text"
    Else 

        mailBody = "No items selected."
    End If
    GetMailBody = mailBody
End Function
```

To use this function replace the line

```
.Body = "Hi," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please see comment below"
```

with

```
.Body = GetMailBody()
```

in your existing code.

### EDIT

Updated code to include alternative text, when no items selected.

Comment: This is amazing now I got the result that I want. What if there is no checkbox selected and the email body message should be "No Changes needed."

Comment: Adding a counter would allow you to do this.  I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you it helps a lot to my project. Much appreciated.

Comment: How to retain email signature?

Comment: Is the signature stored in Outlook?

Comment: Yes it was stored in Outlook

Comment: I'm not sure.  I thought it would be easy but digging around inside Outlook didn't get me anywhere.  One method is to recreate the signature in code and append that (`sig = "With Kind Regards..."` -> `mailBody = "some text " & vbCrLf & sig`).

Comment: I will create a new signature for this. Thank you for all the inputs. Have a great day.

Comment: I know the reason why is the stored signature were being  removed, because the .Body = Getmail so the stored signature deleted once the Getmail call by the code.

Comment: Got it!  So you could fix using `.Body = GetMail() & .Body`?

Comment: Yup its working but I'm having a problem with with embedded email add link.

Comment: There are two ways to update the body: Body and BodyHTML. You need the second to include links/formatting etc. You can use BodyHTML on an existing mail to extract the signature.

Comment: How to separate the HTMLBody to target the link?